# how to change php headers on respective website using ajax

Tags: php, html, css, ajax, forms

contactfrm.php

```
    <?php

// Server side validation

$name = $_POST['name'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$bsubject = $_POST['subject'];
$email= $_POST['email'];
$message= $_POST['message'];
$to = "sample@email.com";
$subject = "Mail From sample 1";
$cc = "sample@email.com";
$txt ="";
$txt .="<html><body>";
$txt .= "<table style='border-collapse: collapse; width: 30%; background: #ddd7d769;'><tr>
<th style='border: 1px solid #0000004f; text-align: left; padding: 8px;'>Name</th>";
$txt .= "<td  style='  border: 1px solid #0000004f;text-align: left;padding: 8px;'>".$name."</td></tr>";
$txt .= "<tr><th style='border: 1px solid #0000004f; text-align: left; padding: 8px;'>Surname</th>";
$txt .= "<td style='border: 1px solid #0000004f; text-align: left; padding: 8px;'>".$surname."</td></tr>";

$txt .= "<tr><th style='border: 1px solid #0000004f; text-align: left; padding: 8px;'>Subject</th>";
$txt .= "<td style='border: 1px solid #0000004f; text-align: left; padding: 8px;'>".$bsubject."</td></tr>";

$txt .= "<tr style='background: lightgrey;'><th style='border: 1px solid #0000004f; text-align: left; padding: 8px;'>Email</th>";
$txt .= "<td style='border: 1px solid #0000004f; text-align: left; padding: 8px;'>".$email."</td></tr>";
$txt .= "<tr><th style='border: 1px solid #0000004f; text-align: left; padding: 8px;'>Message</th>";
$txt .= "<td style='border: 1px solid #0000004f; text-align: left; padding: 8px;'>".$message."</td></tr>";
$txt .= "</table>";
$txt .="</body></html>";


$headers = "From: Sample 1 . "\r\n" ;

$headers .= 'Cc: '.$cc . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0'.PHP_EOL'\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

        if(!empty($email))
        {
            mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
            $success_output = "Your message sent successfully, We will contact you soon. Thank You";
        }
        else
        {
            $error_output = "Something went wrong. Please try again later";
        }

$output = array(
    'error'     =>  $error_output,
    'success'   =>  $success_output
);

// Output needs to be in JSON format
echo json_encode($output);

?>
```

Contact Form.html

```
<section id="contact" class="contact">
      <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up">

        <div class="section-title">
          <h2>Contact</h2>
          <p>Feel Free to contact</p>
        </div>

        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-lg-5 d-flex align-items-stretch">
            <div class="info">
              <div class="address">
                <a class="skype" href="skype:live:.cid.123456789?chat" target = "_blank"><i class="fa fa-skype" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a class="skype" href="skype:live:.cid.123456789?chat" target = "_blank"><h4>Skype</h4></a>
                <p>Click here to message us directly on Skype</p>
              </div>    


              <div class="address">
                <a class="whatsapp" href="https://wa.me/+123456789" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a class="whatsapp" href="https://wa.me/+123456789" target="_blank"><h4>WhatsApp</h4></a>
                <p>Click here to message us directly on WhatsApp  </p>
              </div>    

              <div class="email">
                <a href = "mailto: sample@email.com"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></a>
                <h4>Email:</h4>
                <a href = "mailto: sample@email.com"><p>sample@email.com</p></a>
              </div>

              <div class="phone">
                <a href="tel:+123456789" target = "_blank"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <h4>Call:</h4>
                <a href="tel:+123456789"><p>+123456789</p></a>
              </div>

              
            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-7 mt-5 mt-lg-0 d-flex align-items-stretch">
            <form id="contactfrm" onsubmit="validateCaptcha()" method = "POST" role="form" class="php-email-form">
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="name">First Name</label>
                  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Your First Name" class="form-control" id="name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" required />
                  <div class="validate"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="name">Surname</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Surname" name="surname" id="surname" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
                  <div class="validate"></div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Your Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="example@example.com" id="email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
                <div class="validate"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Subject</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject" />
                <div class="validate"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Message</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="10" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something for us" required></textarea>
                <div class="validate"></div>
              </div>
              <div id="captcha">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Captcha" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please Enter the Captcha" id="cpatchaTextBox"/>
            </div>
              <div class="text-center" id="btnSend"><button type="submit">Send Message</button></div>
              <div id="alert"></div>
            </form>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </section><!-- End Contact Section -->
```

ajax script

```
<script async = "true">
  var code;
function createCaptcha() {
document.getElementById('captcha').innerHTML = "";
var charsArray =
"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ@";
var lengthOtp = 6;
var captcha = [];
for (var i = 0; i < lengthOtp; i++) {
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * charsArray.length + 1); 
if (captcha.indexOf(charsArray[index]) == -1)
captcha.push(charsArray[index]);
else i--;
}
var canv = document.createElement("canvas");
canv.id = "captcha";
canv.width = 100;
canv.height = 50;
var ctx = canv.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "25px Georgia";
ctx.strokeText(captcha.join(""), 0, 30);
code = captcha.join("");
document.getElementById("captcha").appendChild(canv);
}
function validateCaptcha() {
event.preventDefault();
debugger
if (document.getElementById("cpatchaTextBox").value == code) {
// alert("Valid Captcha")
readCap();
}else{
alert("Invalid Captcha. try Again");
createCaptcha();
}
}

function readCap(){
              $.ajax({
            url: 'contactfrm.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: $('#contactfrm').serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function( _response ){
              
                var error = _response.error;
                var success = _response.success;
                console.log(success);
                if(error != null) {
                    
                    $('#alert').html(error);
                }
                else {
                   
                    $('#alert').html(success);
                    $('#btnSend').remove();
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXhr, json, errorThrown){
               
                var error = jqXhr.responseText;
                $('#alert').html(error);
            }
        });
        }
</script>
```

[image]

I have 30 different websites with this same contact form at the bottom.

As shown in the image, When I receive an email, it says "Mail From (website Name)"
So, if I have to upload same php for 30 different websites, I'll have to make 30 different php forms with different titles and headers.

How can I add if else loop where I can target respective website and only its header will be displayed. Because right now I have created 10 different 'contactfrm.php' in which I have changed headers to respective website.

Comment: You mean you want the script to automatically detect which site it is installed on, and change the email subject accordingly?

Comment: Something like `include("site-settings-config-or-whatever.php");` and a variable should do.

Comment: you have lots of forms but you want to make only one email php function which is added in all forms ?

Comment: @ADyson yes if it works that way, or an if else ladder

Comment: @RakeshkumarOad yes. that's correct, but the function should return the website name as well in the email. Suppose the mail is coming from abc.com then email header should be abc.com like 30 different headers, So there will be a if else ladder, like if(websitename == abc.com){ header = abc} like that

Comment: then you have to add input field in all forms  with type="hidden" and $subject = $_POST['subject'];

Answer (score 1):

Replace this variable

```
$subject = "Mail From sample 1";
```

Into this code you will get your solution .

```
$regexp = "/([\w]{0,}).([\w]{2,3}|[\w]{2,3}.[\w]{2,3})$/";
$url= $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$input = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
preg_match($regexp, $input, $matches);
$subject = "Mail From ".$matches[1];  //out put domain name
```